# Replace Javascript hyperlink with Javascript button

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, imagebutton

I'm a newby here. Just cutting my teeth with Javascript. I've spent a long time today going through every forum I can trying to find a solution to this. I'm finding it fun learning this stuff!

Anyways, I'm working with the following script that does a call-to-action link with jw player...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Call to Action</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/6/jwplayer.js'>
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { 
        margin: 0; padding: 0 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("player").setup({
  playlist: [{
    image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/w5co0c24-480.jpg",
    sources: [{
      file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/w5co0c24-hV866gPy.mp4"
    },{
      file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/w5co0c24-hV866gPy.webm"
    }]
  }],
  width: 600,
  height: 300,
  stretching: "fill"
});

jwplayer().onComplete(function() {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    var el2 = document.createElement("div");
    var el3 = document.createElement("div");
    var el4 = document.createElement("div");
    var txt = document.createElement('a');
    if (jwplayer().getRenderingMode() == "html5"){
    var theBody = document.getElementById(player.id);
    } else {
    var theBody = document.getElementById(player.id+"_wrapper");
    }
    var playerWidthPX2 = theBody.style.width;
    var playerWidthPX = parseFloat(playerWidthPX2);
    var playerHeightPX2 = theBody.style.height;
    var playerHeightPX = parseFloat(playerHeightPX2);   
    el3.setAttribute('id', 'bg');
    el3.style.height = playerHeightPX + "px";
    el3.style.width = playerWidthPX2;
    el3.style.background = "#333333";
    el3.style.opacity = "0.70";
    el3.style.position = "absolute";
    el3.style.backgroundImage="url('background.png')";
    el.setAttribute('src', 'background.png');
    if (jwplayer().getRenderingMode() == "html5"){
    } else {
    el3.style.top = playerHeightPX-playerHeightPX+"px";
    }
    el3.style.zIndex = "999";
    el3.width = playerWidthPX;
    el3.height = playerHeightPX;
    el2.setAttribute('id', 'bg2');
    el2.style.height = playerHeightPX + "px";
    el2.style.width = playerWidthPX2;
    el2.style.position = "absolute";
    el2.style.zIndex = "999";
    el2.width = playerWidthPX;
    el2.height = playerHeightPX;
    theBody.appendChild(el3); 
    theBody.appendChild(el2);
    el2.style.textAlign = "center";
    el2.style.left = ((playerWidthPX*2)/6) -"5" + "px";
    el2.style.top = ((playerHeightPX*3)/6) -"30" + "px";
    el.setAttribute('id', 'hyperlink');
    el.style.height = "30px";
    el.style.width = "30px";
    el2.width = "30";
    el2.height = "30";
    el.style.position = "relative";
    el.setAttribute('frameBorder', '0');
    el.style.top = "11px";
    el.style.left = "202px";
    el.style.textAlign = "center";
    el.style.marginBottom = "-16px";
    el.style.marginRight = "8px";
    var message = 'Did you like the Trailer?<br />Then <u>see the full movie!    </u>';
    txt.innerHTML = message;
    txt.href = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEgQM6ZhkWg";
    txt.target = "_blank";
    txt.style.textDecoration = "none";
    txt.style.outline = "0";
    txt.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
    txt.style.KhtmlUserSelect = 'none';
    txt.style.WebkitUserSelect = 'none';
    txt.style.OUserSelect = 'none';
    txt.style.UserSelect = 'none';
    txt.style.fontSize = "18px";
    txt.style.color = "#ffffff"
    txt.style.position = "absolute";
    txt.style.marginLeft = "6px";
    txt.style.marginTop = "4px";
    txt.style.fontFamily = "arial,_sans";
    txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt');
    el4.setAttribute('id', 'replay');
    el4.style.height = "20px";
    el4.style.width = "20px";
    el4.height = "20";
    el4.width = "20";
    el4.style.position = "absolute";
    el4.style.top = "-" + playerHeightPX/2 + "px";
    el4.style.marginTop = "50px";
    el4.style.left = playerWidthPX/2 + "px";
    el4.style.marginLeft = "50px";
    el4.style.backgroundImage="url('replay.png')";
    el4.setAttribute('src', 'replay.png');
    el2.appendChild(txt);
    el2.appendChild(el);
    el2.appendChild(el4);
    el.style.backgroundImage="url('hyperlink.png')";
    el.setAttribute('src', 'hyperlink.png');
    el.style.cursor = "pointer";
    el.style.display = "table";
    el2.style.display = "table";
    el3.style.display = "table";
    el4.style.display = "table";
    txt.style.display = "table";
    el.onmouseup = function(){
    window.open("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEgQM6ZhkWg");
    }
    el4.style.cursor = "pointer";
    el4.onmouseup = function(){
    el.style.display = "none";
    el2.style.display = "none";
    el3.style.display = "none";
    el4.style.display = "none";
    txt.style.display = "none";
    jwplayer().play();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to replace the text with a button. Specifically, this button...

```
  <a href="http://www.google.com/"
onMouseOver="return changeImage()"
onMouseOut= "return changeImageBack()"
onMouseDown="return handleMDown()"
onMouseUp="return handleMUp()"
><img
name="jsbutton" src="http://disc.maximumimpact.ca/button/ClickHere-Normal.png"     width="402" height="127" border="0"
alt="javascript button"></a>

<script language="JavaScript">

upImage = new Image();
upImage.src = "http://disc.maximumimpact.ca/button/ClickHere-Rollover.png";
downImage = new Image();
downImage.src = "http://disc.maximumimpact.ca/button/ClickHere-Click.png"
normalImage = new Image();
normalImage.src = "http://disc.maximumimpact.ca/button/ClickHere-Normal.png";

function changeImage()
{
  document.images["jsbutton"].src= upImage.src;
  return true;
}
function changeImageBack()
{
   document.images["jsbutton"].src = normalImage.src;
   return true;
}
function handleMDown()
{
 document.images["jsbutton"].src = downImage.src;
 return true;
}
function handleMUp()
{
 changeImage();
 return true;
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help? I would like the video to end and then have the button appear in the centre of the video with the background greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

One nitty gritty way of doing this is to remove

```
var message = 'Did you like the Trailer?<br />Then <u>see the full movie!    </u>';
txt.innerHTML = message;
txt.href = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEgQM6ZhkWg";
txt.target = "_blank";
txt.style.textDecoration = "none";
txt.style.outline = "0";
txt.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
txt.style.KhtmlUserSelect = 'none';
txt.style.WebkitUserSelect = 'none';
txt.style.OUserSelect = 'none';
txt.style.UserSelect = 'none';
txt.style.fontSize = "18px";
txt.style.color = "#ffffff"
txt.style.position = "absolute";
txt.style.marginLeft = "6px";
txt.style.marginTop = "4px";
txt.style.fontFamily = "arial,_sans";
txt.setAttribute('id', 'txt');
```

Because it is no longer necessary.
Then after `el2.appendChild(txt);` put

```
txt.outerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com/" onMouseOver="return changeImage()" onMouseOut= "return changeImageBack()" onMouseDown="return handleMDown()" onMouseUp="return handleMUp()"><img name="jsbutton" src="http://disc.maximumimpact.ca/button/ClickHere-Normal.png"     width="402" height="127" border="0" alt="javascript button"></a>';
```

It has to happen after `appendChild()` because you can't set the `outerHTML` until it has been appended to the DOM.  You want to make sure that all your event functions (e.g. `changeImage`) are defined, so put your script into the HTML as well.

A much better way of doing this is to use JavaScript functions to properly recreate this button.  That means that you would do something along the lines of

```
var button = document.createElement('a');
button.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
button.addEventListener('mouseover', changeImage); // Make sure you define changeImage
... // Create all the child elements and set their respective properties in JavaScript
el2.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: This works awesome! The only thing I need some direction on is where to adjust the button's placement. It appears way too far to the right of the player window. See this screenshot: http://maximumimpact.ca/images/Screenshot-js.png What elements would I play with to adjust that?

Comment: You modify it's top and left CSS properties, or if that doesn't work modify its margin properties.